# Not able to resolve subdomain externally ( windows server 2008 r2)

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I have set up my own dns server. I have configured it and it works from outside. Then after I created some sub-domain with (subdomain.mydomain.com  which is 'A Record') and try to access it from internet it doesn't work. It works from internal network. 
My set up is like

I have set up 1 domain controller. I have hosted main domain site on controller it self. 
I have one another web server which has some other sites for subdomains.

So while creating subdomain with A record I provided the ip of the other webserver where site for that domain is hosted. and in Websserver / In site hosting I set the binding with the name of subdomain.

It resolves the subdomain from internal network but not from outside internet.

Does it take time to propogate changes to internet? Cause I am really a newbie..

Can anyone please help me out - how to resolve this issue. ?

Thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes DNS servers will cache `NXDOMAIN` responses (so if you or anyone tried to query the domain before you set it up, it will appear to not exist for however long the DNS server you're querying wants to cache that response for).  They often do this longer than your TTL even if you don't want or expect it.  If a DNS server hasn't had a query for your domain yet, it will always query your DNS server because it hasn't seen anything to cache.

Comment: So What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: Wait.  Try using a tool like dig to query your external DNS directly, preferably from outside your network, to ensure that it is at least serving the record.  If it is, you can't do anything to speed up convergence.  If it isn't, you'll have to troubleshoot (are you using split-horizon DNS?).

Answer (score -1):

You should set up a DNS service on a hosted service such as DNSmadeeasy.com

Your DNS server needs to be add as a "nameserver" for your domain.  A DNS or domain registrar can do something like that for you.  If I understand your question correctly your DNS server is just sitting on the internet.  When people look up your domain there is no path to your DNS Server.

I don't thinks you really need a DNS server.  You could just sign up for a DNS service and have your domain names point to your IP address

Comment: My main domain ( www.mydomain.com) working perfectly fine from the internet.. But only issue is I am not able to access my sub-domains from internet.

Comment: Hosting your own DNS is often a good idea.  For instance, if you want to roll out DNSSEC, or have split-horizon DNS, or create experimental or uncommon record types, many shared hosting style DNS providers will not work out.  All you need are two DNS servers with different public IPs.